# How to prevent new tab opening during form submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a registration form to be submitted which performs some activities like saving user details to database, address proof as image to database and sends email to user giving username and password. On clicking submit button, control goes to new tab and then only the control goes to CS file.

My code is:

```
protected void sub2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    incentiveClass.dbPerform dbc = new incentiveClass.dbPerform();

    string custname = iname.Value;
    custemail = iemail.Value;

    string datebir = datepicker.Value;


    string cadd1 = addr1.Value;
    string cadd2 = add2.Value;
    dt = dbc.conid(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    string ctry = dt.Rows[0]["CountryID"].ToString();
    string sta = state1.Value;
    string city = icity.Value;
    string pin = ipin.Value;
    string pann = ipan.Value;
    string cno = icno.Value;
    string mobil = imobe.Value;
    string faxx = ifx.Value;

    pwd = PasswordCreation(10);

    string filePath = addproof.PostedFile.FileName;
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    string contenttype = String.Empty;

    //Set the contenttype based on File Extension
    switch (ext)
    {
        case ".doc":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".docx":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".xls":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case ".jpg":
            contenttype = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case ".png":
            contenttype = "image/png";
            break;
        case ".gif":
            contenttype = "image/gif";
            break;
        case ".pdf":
            contenttype = "application/pdf";
            break;
    }
    if (contenttype != String.Empty)
    {

        Stream fs = addproof.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        add1 = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        Label1.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        Label1.Text = "File format not recognised." +
          " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";
        Response.Redirect("register.aspx");
    }

    string filePath1 = pancopy.PostedFile.FileName;
    string filename1 = Path.GetFileName(filePath1);
    string ext1 = Path.GetExtension(filename1);
    string contenttype1 = String.Empty;

    //Set the contenttype based on File Extension
    switch (ext1)
    {
        case ".doc":
            contenttype1 = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".docx":
            contenttype1 = "application/vnd.ms-word";
            break;
        case ".xls":
            contenttype1 = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case ".xlsx":
            contenttype1 = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case ".jpg":
            contenttype1 = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case ".png":
            contenttype1 = "image/png";
            break;
        case ".gif":
            contenttype1 = "image/gif";
            break;
        case ".pdf":
            contenttype1 = "application/pdf";
            break;
    }
    if (contenttype1 != String.Empty)
    {

        Stream fs1 = pancopy.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br1 = new BinaryReader(fs1);
        pan = br1.ReadBytes((Int32)fs1.Length);


        Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        Label2.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        Label2.Text = "File format not recognised." +
          " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";
        Response.Redirect("register.aspx");
    }


    Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
    string random = g.ToString();

    dbc.Cuscode = random.Substring(0, 4);
    dbc.Customer_name = custname;
    dbc.Email = custemail;
    dbc.Dateob = datebir;

    dbc.Add1 = cadd1;
    dbc.Add2 = cadd2;
    dbc.Country = ctry;
    dbc.State = sta;
    dbc.Pin = pin;
    dbc.Panno = pann;
    dbc.Phone = cno;
    dbc.Mobile1 = mobil;
    dbc.Fax = faxx;
    dbc.Pawd = pwd;
    dbc.Bytes = add1;
    dbc.Bytes1 = pan;
    int flag = dbc.regstr(icity.Value);
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MessagePopUp", "alert('Registration Successfull!!! Mail will be sent to your Email Id!!!');", true);
    }

    try 
    {
        Response.Redirect("userhome.aspx",false);
        SendMail();              
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMessage(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: in the code you post there is no call to open a new tab. maybe some client code is missing?

Comment: Thanks.Can you give some suggestions about what might have been missed.

Comment: you may have missed some client code that opens a new window/tab. you provide no client code so i have no way to give you any advice better than that.

Comment: @Narayanaswamy can you shows us the aspx code of the submit button?

Comment: Check the target property of form. is it "_blank" ? If yes, remove it

Comment: thank you all for your effort. I had defined target property of the form to a 'Iframe'. I just removed that and now my code is working properly.